# Regular expression to match this simple pattern

Tags: regex

I need help matching a simple pattern, through regular expression.

If a string (used for url) ends with '/' (without single qoutes) and some more string, then it's true. If it end with just '/' (without single qoutes), then its false. 
So example these are all true:

- /da/
- /da/test1/
- /da/test1/test2/

These are all false:

- /
- /da
- /da/test1
- /da/test1/test2

I'm close, but no luck. Please help me modify my regular expression. This is what I have:

```
^(.*)/$
```

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using for this?

Comment: It's in a web.config file of C#

Comment: @DmitryPoroh please make your response as an answer, so I can accept you. It was correct, thanks for your help.

Comment: cant you just check with EndsWith() function..?

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar yes, it's smarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need too use '+' wildcard that cause match one or more preceding expression:

```
^.+/$
```

Moreover in this case brackets are excessive if you don't need result of match.

Comment: Why catching previous characters?

Comment: @CWürtz what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I read an expression with parenthesis. 
This regex start from the beginning of the string. But we don't need to check the whole string.

Comment: Or just `/$`. But if you check only the last char, you should not use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a system where the / character is used as the delimiter for the regular expression? If so, you have to escape that character as well, so the final Regex statement would be:

```
/(.*)\/$/
```

Comment: Be careful, you match the string `/` but it must be false.

Answer (score 0):

Why catching previous symbols?

```
#./$#
```

Any character (`.`),
then the `/` character,
last the end symbol (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use groups, as you can simply check whether or not the pattern matches the input string. Your pattern should match if the input string starts and ends with a forward slash. You can use the following regular expression for this.

```
/^\/.*\/$/
```

This pattern will also match `//`. If this is not something you want you can simply replace the asterisk (`*`) with a plus (`+`).